# trouble getting filereader image upload demo to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image

Right now I am trying to implement the [Mozilla filereader image uploader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) in AngularJS, but for some reason I am getting stuck. This is the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YE0TS51L9LgA5l7wARg6?p=preview) of what I have at the moment.

I know it's this line:

```
<img ng-src="image" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

But I don't know what to do to fix it.